# How can I set up my Linux server to permit password login for sftp only, and require public private key for ssh?

Tags: ssh, sftp, useradd, ssh-config

I have a Linux server which I have configured to login with public private key for my account - and it works well.  It's a long time since I set it up, so I can't remember what steps I took - but it's configured so that logon with password is disallowed.  If I try to log on (whether with ssh or sftp) from a system which doesn't have the right keys then I get the following error (as expected) `Permission denied (publickey,password)`

Now I need to add a new user to the system, who will need to be able to edit all of the web pages in one directory of the webserver.  The directory that they need to access already exists.  This user will need to be able to access using sftp only, and all other logins will be prohibited.  In addition, I want this user to be able to log in using a password - not public private key.  I set up the user as follows:

```
sudo useradd -g sftpusers -d /home/ethereal/lemp-compose/public/promopages -s /sbin/nologin promoadmin
```

I then checked that the new user had been created as follows

```
grep promoadmin /etc/passwd
```

I changed the owner of the existing directory that they need to access as follows:

```
sudo chown -R promoadmin:sftpusers /home/ethereal/lemp-compose/public/promopages
```

And set a password for the account:

```
sudo passwd promoadmin
```

Now I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - and this is where things get weird. Given the way that the system is currently working, I **expected** to see (amongst other things) the following (as I say, I can't remember the steps that I took to set this server up all those years ago)

```
PermitRootLogin no 
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

PasswordAuthentication no
```

What I **actually** see is

```
PermitRootLogin no 
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

PasswordAuthentication yes
```

And then, further down:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes

AllowUsers etherealadmin promoadmin
AllowGroups sftpusers

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Match Group sftpusers
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Having done that I restarted ssh

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

With the config that I have I would expect to be able to log in (using both ssh and sftp) with either password or public / private key - but this clearly isn't the case.  I'd also expect to be able to log in using sftp for the promoadmin user.  It doesn't work though.  The etherealadmin user works for ssh and sftp using public private key only, and I can't get promoadmin to work at all!

I've clearly messed this up - I'd be very grateful to anyone who can work out what's gone wrong and help me clear up this mess!

---

Part 2, with thanks to all those who have made suggestions so far.

Attempting to log in using the -v option yields the following result (IP address obfuscated as irrelevant)

```
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/headbanger/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/headbanger/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/headbanger/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/headbanger/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
promoadmin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.3.9
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Received message too long 1416128883
Ensure the remote shell produces no output for non-interactive sessions.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2412, received 2712 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3002.2, received 3375.6
debug1: Exit status 1
```

This is after fixing one issue where the /usr/sbin/nologin shell was initially mis-specified.  So we're possibly closer to a solution.  It's also worth noting that /usr/sbin/nologin is not included in /etc/shells, just in case that's part of the issue.

All thoughts welcome!

Comment: As far as I can tell, having `/sbin/nologin` as a user's shell configured in `/etc/passwd` prevents both SSH and SFTP login. As a minor point, it doesn't look clear to me which parts of your `sshd_config` you've actually changed.

Comment: Also, `Permission denied (publickey,password)` implies that password authentication is allowed. Seeing it without being prompted for a password may indicate that some _client_-side configuration equivalent to `PasswordAuthentication=no` is in effect. A look at the output of `ssh -v` may be of help.

Comment: You probably should use a ForceCommand in the Match block to enforce sftp only (rather than setting the login shell to /sbin/nologin)

Comment: Have you dug into the "Received message too long" error? There isn't much about it on U&L, but I see search engines return a few hits for it. (But, unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue based on the answers I had found).